# merging/subsetting dataframe doesn't recognize certain numbers in column

Tags: r, merge, numeric

I want to merge two dataframes by a shared column value, which works for 6,000+ of the rows but fails for about 600 rows (97 unique values).

Basically, I have a numeric column in the df but some specific values are not being understood as numbers, even if the class is indeed numeric. Examples:

A working value of "Query.Mass" in the df:

```
> class(df$Query.Mass)
[1] "numeric" # all values here should be numeric
> sum(df$Query.Mass==100.0760)
[1] 1 #ok good, there's one row with that value
> df[df$Query.Mass==100.0760,]
      unq_id class esi_mode Query.Mass Retention.Time WCMC_Annot Species_WCMC
11709   A561 amine  ESI pos    100.076           1.88       <NA>         <NA>
# good, we can see that entry by searching on Query.Mass
```

But one of the problem values, in the same dataframe:

```
> df[df$unq_id=="L66",]
     unq_id class esi_mode Query.Mass Retention.Time WCMC_Annot Species_WCMC
4548    L66 lipid      neg   124.0075            0.6       <NA>         <NA>
# here we see that the entry known as L66 has 124.0075 as Query.Mass
> sum(df$Query.Mass==124.0075)
[1] 0 # but it isn't being found by this method
> df[df$Query.Mass==124.0075,]
[1] unq_id         class          esi_mode       Query.Mass     Retention.Time WCMC_Annot     Species_WCMC  
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
# trying to pull rows that have that 124.0075 value also fails

# if I treat the value like a character, it works
> df[df$Query.Mass=="124.0075",]
      unq_id class esi_mode Query.Mass Retention.Time WCMC_Annot Species_WCMC
4548     L66 lipid      neg   124.0075           0.60       <NA>         <NA>
10453  A2090 amine  ESI neg   124.0075           8.44       <NA>         <NA>
# totally fine to to have two values for my purposes, this shouldn't stop me from being able to search for 124.0075 as number
```

I'm kind of baffled, how can certain values in the same column that has a class set as col_number/numeric be only searchable as a character? I suspect this is what is causing my merge problem (L66 was one of those rows that should have merged in, but was missed)

```
# the merge command that only partially works, and led me to find these trouble rows
merge(df_2,df, by=c("Query.Mass","Retention.Time"))
```

Comment: Greetings! Its much easier to help you if we have some form of data to work with. Please provide a reproducible dataset, such as using the `dput` command and sharing the output here. You can learn how to do so here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to StackOverflow and no expert and probably can't help you much, but I'll post my thoughts anyway, maybe it helps at tiny little bit. This is one of my first contributions, so please don't be too hard on me if my answer is not perfect. If I write any nonsense, I am happy about any comments which correct me.

1. Have you tried to convert the column into a numeric with as.numeric(...)? Or maybe convert it to character first and then to numeric, i.e. as.numeric(as.character(...))?
2. Do you maybe have any NAs in this column, which are no "real" NAs, but character?
3. Do you have imported your data from csv? If yes, it might help to change the import settings.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses, in the end it was something to do with an additional digit being added to the end of certain values in one df somehow during data wrangling/analysis outputs. The extra digits went past what was easily spotted with scrolling through the csv in excel or the R outputs above. Dumb stuff, as usual. Once I combed through and truncated the values to become exact matches again, merge() worked fine.